# switch schematic and simulation

Tags: switches

[image]

Here is my switch schematic and simulation,but when the control(red) is off,is't it the output(purple) be 0 whatever i(black) is 1 or 0?Is there any method can modify this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to switch on and off a signal passed through a transmission gate (aka analogue switch). Your output is not connected to anything so here's a problem - even if the analogue switch open-circuited up to 100 Mohms, you would still see a signal at the output.

MOSFETs have a finite open-circuit impedance of a few Mohms at best and, they also have quite high drain-source capacitance so you are bound to get some leak-through of the signal when the gate is off.

Try loading the output with 1 kohm and see what happens.

Comment: Is my thinking right?When control is 1,output is rail to rail,when control is 0,output is not rail to rail

Comment: When control is 1, output = input generally but can saturate at a value.

Comment: So when control is 1,and the input is 0~1.8v square wave.if the output is rail to rail,output voltage have to be 0~1.8v?

Comment: My best advice is for you to simulate this circuit.

Comment: i had simulated it,when control is 0,output does become 0v,but the output ,when control is 1, become less than 1.8v

Comment: Probably because your MOSFETs are not switching on fully AND with the load I recommended the on-resistance forms a potential divider with the 1 kohm.

Comment: Yes,i did connect the loading resistor with 1k ohm